# Relationship between variance and tail bounds

Tags: probability

Assume you have two positive discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the same mean $\mu$.  I have two closely related questions.

1. If $Var(X) < Var(Y)$,  what do we know about the relationship between $P(X >k)$ and $P(Y>k)$, if $k > \mu$.
2. If $Var(X) = Var(Y)$,  what do we know about the relationship between $P(X > k)$ and $P(Y>k)$, if $k > \mu$.

This comes about because of my confusion about the answer to [Probability a rotation has a small distance to a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286899/probability-a-rotation-has-a-small-distance-to-a-vector) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Markov's inequality,
if $k > \mu$ then  $P(X > k) < \mu/k$ and similarly for $Y$.
You can also get bounds involving the variance, e.g. from Chebyshev's inequality. 
But in most cases, you can't say which of $P(X>k)$ and $P(Y>k)$ is greater.

EDIT: You can get a lower bound as follows.  If $0 \le X \le L$, note that
for $0 < k < L$ we have $I_{x > k} \ge \dfrac{x (x - k)}{L (L-k)}$ where $I_{x > k}$ is the indicator function of $x \ge k$.  Therefore $$P(X > k) \ge E\left[ \dfrac{X(X-k)}{L(L-k)}\right] = \dfrac{\sigma^2 + \mu^2 - k \mu}{L(L-k)}$$
This is best possible in the sense that it is an equality if the only possible values of
$X$ are $0, k, L$.